# Is it possible to put "|" character in a vimwiki table cell?

Tags: filetype-markdown, plugin-vimwiki

vimwiki tables are auto-formattable.
This is very convenient but I'm in trouble when I'm trying to make this kind of table.

```
|       | Composites             | 
| `xy`  | `x` followed by `y`    |
| `x|y` | `x' or `y` (prefer `x`)|
```

As you see, this table has delimiter character `|` in a cell.
So when I'm trying to edit this table, it turns into as below automatically.

```
|      | Composites          |                         |
| `xy` | `x` followed by `y` |                         |
| `x   | y`                  | `x` or `y` (prefer `x`) |
```

I can bypass this problem by replacing `|` character with similar symbol character. 
But I'm curious if there is another solution for this problem.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick google search using `vimwiki pipe character in table` and first result is a report in the VimWiki issue list: https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/281

There we find:

> There is currently no way to make the table formatting code ignore certain pipe characters. A quick and dirty "solution" is to write a vertical bar instead of a pipe (you get it in Vim by typing Ctrl+k v v). But yes, there should be a way.

That vertical bar, which looks like this `│`, is a decent substitute for `|`, if you ask me.